# Grabbing an existing ArrayList and adding values onto it from a getter

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm wondering how would I be able to grab the currents values from an ArrayList and add-on values to it.

```
 private List<String> friends;

public Profile(List<String> friends){
  this.friends = friends
 }

public List<String> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
   this.friends = getFriends() + friends;
}
```

Obviously, the method "addFriend" won't working because an operator cannot be applied to an ArrayList. It supposes to be an example of how it should exactly work. Grabbing getFriends() method and applying another list to it. So is there a way that I can accomplish this task? Grabbing a getter ArrayList and adding values ONTO it.

Note: Already assumed that the data is stored somewhere in an hashmap with a key and a value as an List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate and add to the `friends` field? It's already a list...

```
public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
    for (String friend : friends) {
        this.friends.add(friend);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you like to re-invent `Collection#addAll`? ;P

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
   this.friends.addAll(friends);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList.addAll(Collection c)` method:

```
public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
   this.friends.addAll(friends);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different methods:

This way you add a list of friends to the current list

```
public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
   this.friends.addAll(friends);
}
```

This way you only add one friend

```
public void addFriend(String friend) {
   this.friends.add(friend);
}
```

With this approach you will have two different behaviours for adding friends.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers will work, I might as well add a my own solution as well.

```
public void addFriend(List<String> friends) {
     this.friends.addAll(friends.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: The only downside to this is that you are creating unnecessary objects, which will just slow the computer down, and use more resources (such as memory). the `add` methods and `addAll` methods are more readable and more efficient with resources.